# casting byte array to signed short in python

Tags: python, struct, byte, unpack

I want to convert a *bytearray* type or a list of binary strings in python to a signed short list. In fact, I am getting a byte stream from Ethernet and I want to convert them in **signed short**; however, the only way I found in Python is using `struct.unpack` which seems to be slow since it requires a format string to determine the type of each byte.

This format requirement slows in two steps:

1) Required to make a long string for a long array of bytes

2) Required to search one-by-one in the array.

In C++, the following simple code does the job on the entire memory block contained by InBuf:

```
OutBuf = short int[len]
InBuf = char[len*2]
memcpy(&OutBuf, &InBuf, len*2)
```

This skips doing the format search within the byte array as well as the format string construction. Does anyone know a better way to do so in *Python*?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python > 3.2 you could use [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes):

```
int.from_bytes(b, byteorder='little', signed=True)
```

Comment: This does not work since I have a binary string or a list of binary strings like`MyBin = b'12wda121q'` or `MyBin = [b'12was',b'1231ws']` and `int.from_bytes` should be applied on the 2-byte slices to get the true conversion I need. This is still very slow.